# Testing of catching Promise errors

Tags: javascript, promise, jasmine, es6-promise, jestjs

Could you help me to explain how to write tests for catching errors?

For example I have this fake code:

```
export default function someFunc (num) {
    return someOtherFunc(num).then(resp => {
        return resp + 1
    }).catch(() => {
        return 0
    })
}
```

This is Jest test for the previous code. This is success test:

```
test('Should return 3', () => {
    expect.assertions(1)
    return expect(someFunc(2)).resolves.toBe(3)
})
```

I want to test catching errors, how can I make it? This test will failed with error *"Expected one assertion to be called but only received zero assertion calls"*:

```
test('Should return 3', () => {
    expect.assertions(1)
    return expect(someFunc()).rejects.toBe(0)
})
```

Sorry if this question is stupid. I'm just learning promises

Answer (score 0):

If you `return` from the handler, it doesn't reject but resolves with the return value. So in your case you get a promise fulfilled with `0`.

To reject with an error, `throw` it.

Answer (score 0):

The second test is failing because the Promise is not being rejected. Is one of those curious cases of Javascript:
`undefined + 1 => NaN`
No exception is being thrown.

The promise is being resolved with `NaN` and the `rejects` assertion is not called. If you continue scrolling up in the test results, you may see something like:

```
Expected received Promise to reject, instead it resolved to value
  NaN
```

The test is correct, but the function is not behaving as you expected.
A good test!